# Nodemailer "Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" After Gmail API Credentials

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodemailer

Everything is working fine when locally hosted, but when accessing my backend hosted on Heroku I get the error, "Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN". This isn't the first time for me either, I went through this whole troubleshooting struggle. Even after trying different mail services to see if the error would go away, nothing worked. I even got the Gmail API OAuth codes but this error is *still* showing up on Heroku. Any thoughts?

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        service: Gmail,
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASS,
            clientId: process.env.CLIENTID,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENTSECRET,
            refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
```

Heroku: [Console Image for Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWb9C.png)

Answer (score 2):

kindly comment out host: "smtp.gmail.com" as service line below it is sufficient. You may out your password in single quotes in front of pass like this for a quick fix: pass: 'yourpassword',
of course that's not the best way to do it, but it may solve the issue temporarily until you find a better way to do it.